# Return UsbDevice Port (Or unique values)

Tags: java, android, usb

I am creating an activity for an app which uses flashdrives on an Android device with multiple USB ports. Is there any way for me to figure out which port is being used when the device is plugged in? Right now, I have a BroadcastReceiver which detects when a USB is plugged into any port. Using Android's USB class(es), would it be possible to return a value to determine which port is being used or any unique value to differentiate between the ports?